# How to detect elements with identical attribute value in a loop?

Tags: jquery, each

I am looping trough elements with specific class name and I need to get only the ones with unique `data-title` attribute value.

Currently I am getting duplicate values.

http://jsfiddle.net/8XaD9/

```
$('.video-play').each(function (index, element) {
    var mytitle     = $(this).attr('data-title');
    $('.items').append('<li>'+ mytitle +'</li');

});
```

Comment: in any case, this line `$('.items').append('<li>'+ mytitle +'</li');` is missing an `>` in the li-closing-tag

Comment: So do you only want to see one output entry for titles with duplicates, or *no* output of titles with duplicates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just keep track of the titles you have seen.

```
var titlesSeen = [];

$('.video-play').each(function (index, element) {
    var mytitle = $(this).attr('data-title');
    if($.inArray(mytitle, titlesSeen) == -1) {
        $('.items').append('<li>'+ mytitle +'</li>');
        titlesSeen.push(mytitle);
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWu8P/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I write a function to check if an item already exist and if yes then remove it from the list.

**js**

```
$('.video-play').each(function (index, element) {

    var mytitle     = $(this).attr('data-title');

    checkDuplicates(mytitle);

    $('.items').append('<li>'+ mytitle +'</li');

});

function checkDuplicates(mytitle){

    $(".items li").each(function(){

        if(mytitle == $(this).html()){
               $(this).remove();
    }
           });

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8XaD9/6/)

Comment: Though this would work, it's not very efficient. Querying a local variable in the loop would be much faster than querying the DOM each time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic into this:

```
var mytitle = $(this).attr('data-title');

//Add this line to check if it is unique
if($(".video-play[data-title='"+mytitle+"']").toArray().length<2)    
$('.items').append('<li>'+ mytitle +'</li');
```